# Retain first file for each date

Tags: powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I want to keep 5 last generated file in my directory, retaining only the first file of each date, because inside my subfolders, I have generated files multiple times in the same day.

I have multiple folder with subfolder named "old"

```
C:\test\folder1\old
C:\test\toto\old
...
```

So for example in my subfolder I have this :

```
   Mode                LastWriteTime     Length Name                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
----                -------------     ------ ----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

-a---        07/06/2013     12:01  231248950 geofi.ry.7.0.0.159940.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-a---        07/06/2013     12:33  231248506 geofi.ry.7.0.0.159950.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-a---        07/06/2013     14:51  231248957 geofi.ry.7.0.0.159962.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-a---        17/06/2013     19:47  231248860 geofi.ry.7.0.0.160871.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-a---        18/06/2013     11:03  231248480 geofi.ry.7.0.0.160907.zip
-a---        23/06/2013     07:30  231250266 geofi.ry.7.0.0.161571.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
-a---        23/06/2013     21:30  231250266 geofi.ry.7.0.0.161563.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-a---        04/07/2013     00:42  231249910 geofi.ry.7.0.0.162695.zip
-a---        04/07/2013     16:12  231249910 geofi.ry.7.0.0.162647.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
-a---        08/07/2013     16:10  231250481 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163046.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
-a---        10/07/2013     08:40  231250476 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163378.zip                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
-a---        17/07/2013     10:22  231249418 geofi.ry.7.0.0.164001.zip
```

I want to keep theses files :

```
-a---        17/07/2013     10:22  231249418 geofi.ry.7.0.0.164001.zip
-a---        10/07/2013     08:40  231250476 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163378.zip   
-a---        08/07/2013     16:10  231250481 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163046.zip    
-a---        04/07/2013     00:42  231249910 geofi.ry.7.0.0.162695.zip (on this date i have two files, I want to keep the first generated at this date 00:42).
-a---        23/06/2013     07:30  231250266 geofi.ry.7.0.0.161571.zip (on this date i have two files, I want to keep the first generated at this date 07:30).
```

This is a draft but I'm stuck, how can I compare time?

```
$Days = "5"

$TargetFolder = "C:\test\"

$Extension = "*.zip"

 $Files = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | sort-object {$_.LastWriteTime} -Descending | ? { $_.fullname -match "old" } | select-object -First 1

 $most_recent_date = $files.LastWriteTime

 $LastWrite = $most_recent_date.Add(-$Days)

 $Files2 = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite"}  | ? { $_.fullname -match "old" }


 foreach ($File in $Files2) 
    {
    if ($File -ne $NULL)
        {
        Remove-Item $File.FullName | out-null
        }
    else
        {
        Write-Host "No more files to delete!"
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to keep the most recent file of the 5 most recent dates across all folders try this:

```
$TargetFolder = 'C:\test'
$Extension    = '*.zip'

$files = gci $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse |
    ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Directory.Name -eq 'old' }
$keep = $files | sort LastWriteTime -Desc | group {$_.LastWriteTime.Date} |
    % {$_.Group[-1].FullName} | select -First 5
$totalSize = ($files | ? { $keep -notcontains $_.FullName } |
    Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
$files | ? { $keep -notcontains $_.FullName } | Remove-Item -WhatIf

"Deleted size: {0:N3}" -f ($totalSize / 1GB)
```

If you want to keep the most recent file of the 5 most recent dates from each folder try this:

```
$TargetFolder = 'C:\test'
$Extension    = '.zip'
$totalSize    = 0

gci $TargetFolder -Recurse | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -and $_.Name -eq 'old' } | % {
  $files = gci $_.FullName | ? { -not $_.PSIsContainer -and
      $_.Extension -eq $Extension }
  $keep = $files | sort LastWriteTime -Desc | group {$_.LastWriteTime.Date} |
      % {$_.Group[-1].FullName} | select -First 5
  $totalSize += ($files | ? { $keep -notcontains $_.FullName } |
      Measure-Object -Sum Length).Sum
  $files | ? { $keep -notcontains $_.FullName } | Remove-Item -WhatIf
}

"Deleted size: {0:N3}" -f ($totalSize / 1GB)
```

Remove the `-WhatIf`-switch from `Remove-Item` and re-run the code after you double-checked that the code really does what you want.

Comment: It doesn't work correctly, because in one of my subfolders, your script deleted wrong files... 
I want to keep 5 last generated file in my directory, and retaining only the first file of each date.
See my example in my post
Thanks for your help

Comment: @Adeel I had to fix extension filtering in the second example. Other than that the code should do what you want. If it doesn't: show evidence. It worked as expected when I tested it.

Comment: Your second example is good, there is a subtlety.
If i have two files generated on the same date  :
file1.zip 10/07/2013 at 07:00
file2.zip 10/07/2013 at 09:00

I want to keep the file1.zip and not the file2.zip, because file1.zip is the first generated at this date, i don't want to keep the last generated. Thanks for help

Comment: @AdeelASIF I think I got it. Sort order is OK, but you need to select the last instead of the first member from each group (that was the part I had missed before). Try the updated answer.

Comment: Yes it's good now ! :)
Now last thing, how to calculate the total size of deleted files In GB or MB ?
Thanks

Comment: @AdeelASIF You calculate the total size via `Measure-Object -Sum` and divide the result by `1GB` or `1MB` respectively. See updated answer.

Comment: it doesn't work, it gave me `Deleted size: 0,000`
I tested with and without `-WhatIf switch`

Comment: What do you get when you change `1GB` to `1MB` or `1KB` (or print `$totalsize` directly)?

Comment: when i print $totalsize directly it's empty, it displays nothing

Comment: Please show the command with which you calculate `$totalsize`. Even if no files were to be removed, the value should be `0`, not `$null`/empty.

Comment: @AdeelASIF The code in the second example didn't accumulate the sizes of the deleted files of each subfolder, thus processing a folder with no files to delete left the variable empty. If that folder was the last folder processed, the code would report a total size of 0. Please try the updated script.

Comment: The script doesn't work properly in powershell 2.0, this is normal?

Comment: Yes. For PowerShell v2 you need to replace `%{$_.Group[-1].FullName}` with `%{$_.Group|select -Last 1 -Expand FullName}`.

Answer (score 3):

The job can also be done with the help of good old batch with it's built-in associative arrays:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ('dir /a-d /b *.zip') DO (
    FOR /f "tokens=2-4delims=/ " %%b  IN ("%%a") DO SET "filedate=%%d%%c%%b"
    FOR /f "tokens=3" %%b IN ("%%a") DO SET "filetime=%%b"
    SET "$!filedate!$!filetime!=%%a"
)
FOR /f "delims=$" %%a IN ('set "$"') DO (
    IF NOT "%%a"=="!files!" (
        SET "file="
        FOR /f "tokens=2*delims=$=" %%b IN ('set "$%%a"') DO IF NOT DEFINED file SET "file=%%c"
        SET "#%%a=!file!"
        SET "files=%%a"
        SET /a filecount+=1
    )
)
SET /a filecount-=5
FOR /f "skip=%filecount%tokens=2delims==" %%a IN ('set "#"') DO ECHO %%a
```

Session protocol:

```
>dir /a-d *.zip
-a---        07/06/2013     12:01  231248950 geofi.ry.7.0.0.159940.zip
-a---        07/06/2013     12:33  231248506 geofi.ry.7.0.0.159950.zip
-a---        07/06/2013     14:51  231248957 geofi.ry.7.0.0.159962.zip
-a---        17/06/2013     19:47  231248860 geofi.ry.7.0.0.160871.zip
-a---        18/06/2013     11:03  231248480 geofi.ry.7.0.0.160907.zip
-a---        23/06/2013     07:30  231250266 geofi.ry.7.0.0.161571.zip
-a---        23/06/2013     21:30  231250266 geofi.ry.7.0.0.161563.zip
-a---        04/07/2013     00:42  231249910 geofi.ry.7.0.0.162695.zip
-a---        04/07/2013     16:12  231249910 geofi.ry.7.0.0.162647.zip
-a---        08/07/2013     16:10  231250481 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163046.zip
-a---        10/07/2013     08:40  231250476 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163378.zip
-a---        17/07/2013     10:22  231249418 geofi.ry.7.0.0.164001.zip

>script.bat
-a---        23/06/2013     07:30  231250266 geofi.ry.7.0.0.161571.zip
-a---        04/07/2013     00:42  231249910 geofi.ry.7.0.0.162695.zip
-a---        08/07/2013     16:10  231250481 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163046.zip
-a---        10/07/2013     08:40  231250476 geofi.ry.7.0.0.163378.zip
-a---        17/07/2013     10:22  231249418 geofi.ry.7.0.0.164001.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your question that you only want to keep 5 files across all sub folders, if so the code below will do what you want. If you want to keep 5 files per sub folder then you will to create an outer loop of those folders first and then run the code below for each individual folder.

```
$TargetFolder = "C:\test\"

$AllFiles = Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Filter *.zip -Recurse | 
  ? { $_.fullname -match "old" -and -not $_.PSIsContainer  }

$KeepFiles = $AllFiles | 
  Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
  Group-Object {$_.LastWriteTime.Date} | 
  % {$_.Group[0]} | 
  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending |
  Select-Object -First 5

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $AllFiles -DifferenceObject $KeepFiles -PassThru |
  Remove-Item
```

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work properly..
And i want to keep the first file of each date, and retain only the 5 last generated, look at the example I posted

Comment: Discover problem with my code - have made an edit to correct.

Comment: Thanks but it's not good... it deleted almost all of my zip files

Answer (score 1):

What about this one line ?

```
Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse |Sort-Object lastwritetime -Descending | Group-Object @{Expression={($_.lastwritetime).Date}} | % {$_.group | Select-Object -Last 1}
```

1) Get all the files, here you can add the filters you want.

2) Sort the result descending on the lastwritetime.

3) Group the result by date, so I get a group for each date.

4) Get the last element in the goup for each date.

---

I forgot  | Select-Object -First 5

```
Get-Childitem $TargetFolder -Include $Extension -Recurse |Sort-Object lastwritetime -Descending | Group-Object @{Expression={($_.lastwritetime).Date}} | % {$_.group | Select-Object -Last 1} | Select-Object -First 5
```

---

This is working only for one dir try this :

```
Get-ChildItem $TargetFolder -Recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer} | % { Get-ChildItem -Path $_.fullname -filter $Extension |Sort-Object lastwritetime -Descending | Group-Object @{Expression={($_.lastwritetime).Date}} | % {$_.group | Select-Object -Last 1} | Select-Object -First 5}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. What append if you finish with `| Select-Object -First 5`

Comment: it gaves me an error and can you explain me why use ` characters?
ForEach-Object : Cannot bind parameter 'RemainingScripts'. Cannot convert the "|" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock"

Comment: It doesn't works properly see here http://pastebin.com/wMGEJ6zb
And this is the result with `| Select-Object -First 5` http://pastebin.com/ZgttmJf9 Thx

Comment: I don't understand your question. This code works for one folder and subfolders and gives the first file written the five  the last days there were files written.

Comment: I have multiple folder with subfolder named "old", check my first post again ... 

`C:\test\folder1\old`
`C:\test\folder2\old`
I know that i can add | ? { $_.fullname -match "old" } but this is not the issue. 
Your first code without `| Select-Object -First 5` give me good sorting, but i have one duplicated folder in the result ? why ? 

And your second code with `| Select-Object -First 5` doesn't work, it scan only one folder... 
Please check again what i posted on pastebin. Thx

Comment: I make another attempt.